# Installing Jenkins on WSL failing

Tags: linux, ubuntu, windows-subsystem-for-linux, jenkins

I am trying to install Jenkins on WSL (ubuntu on Windows 10) but it is failing somehow and not able to get the running status.
here is the command to install and its output:

```
user@machine:~$ sudo apt install jenkins
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree
Reading state information... Done
The following additional packages will be installed:
daemon
The following NEW packages will be installed:
daemon jenkins
0 upgraded, 2 newly installed, 0 to remove and 0 not upgraded.
Need to get 77.2 MB of archives.
After this operation, 77.7 MB of additional disk space will be used.
Do you want to continue? [Y/n] Y
Get:1 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic/universe amd64 daemon amd64 0.6.4-1build1 [99.5 kB]
Get:2 http://pkg.jenkins.io/debian-stable binary/ jenkins 2.164.1 [77.1 MB]
Fetched 77.2 MB in 40s (1923 kB/s)
Selecting previously unselected package daemon.
(Reading database ... 70496 files and directories currently installed.)
Preparing to unpack .../daemon_0.6.4-1build1_amd64.deb ...
Unpacking daemon (0.6.4-1build1) ...
Selecting previously unselected package jenkins.
Preparing to unpack .../jenkins_2.164.1_all.deb ...
Unpacking jenkins (2.164.1) ...
Processing triggers for ureadahead (0.100.0-20) ...
Processing triggers for systemd (237-3ubuntu10.17) ...
Processing triggers for man-db (2.8.3-2ubuntu0.1) ...
Setting up daemon (0.6.4-1build1) ...
Setting up jenkins (2.164.1) ...
invoke-rc.d: could not determine current runlevel
Processing triggers for systemd (237-3ubuntu10.17) ...
Processing triggers for ureadahead (0.100.0-20) ...

to check the status I run the following command without success:
user@machine:~$ systemctl status jenkins
System has not been booted with systemd as init system (PID 1). Can't operate.
```

any ideas ?

Comment: WSL doesn't support systemd, no systemctl. Try with any sysvinit style scripts.

Answer (score 1):

To install and run Jenkins in WSL, follow these steps:

- Install JDK and JRE:
  `apt install default-jdk default-jre`
- Import the GPG keys:
  `wget -q -O - https://pkg.jenkins.io/debian/jenkins-ci.org.key | sudo apt-key add -`
- Add the Jenkins repository:
  `sudo sh -c 'echo deb http://pkg.jenkins.io/debian-stable binary/ > /etc/apt/sources.list.d/jenkins.list'`
- Update and install:
  `apt update; apt install jenkins`

At the time of writing this answer, WSL does [not support `systemd` init](https://github.com/microsoft/WSL/issues/2530).
So, SysVinit script can be used as an alternative. Run
`sudo /etc/init.d/jenkins start` command to start Jenkins as background daemon.
For personal configuration, add parameters in `/etc/default/jenkins` file.
But there will be no pidfile in `/var/run/jenkins/jenkins.pid` because
of same previous reason. Check the Jenkins install by opening `127.0.0.1:8080`
in any web browser.

#### Further Readings:

- [Debian Wiki: Install Java](https://wiki.debian.org/Java)
- [Installing Jenkins](https://jenkins.io/doc/book/installing/)
- [WSL needs to handle (some) init steps](https://github.com/microsoft/WSL/issues/2530)
- [Blockers for systemd?](https://github.com/Microsoft/WSL/issues/994)
- [invoke-rc.d: could not determine current runlevel](https://github.com/Microsoft/WSL/issues/1761)

Answer (score 0):

use

```
sudo service jenkins status
```